# how to conditionally apply text to data variable based on props in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I conditionally apply value to the data variable based on props, the ternary operator is generating error, I would like to refer to this code:

```
<template>
  <div class="absolute left-3 top-1/2">
    <img
      :src="hamburgerUrl"
      style="width: 25px; cursor: pointer; transform: translateY(-50%)"
      alt="toggle menu button"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HamburgerMenu",
  props: ["white"],
  data: {
    hamburgerUrl: this.white
      ? "/gfx/hamburger-white.png"
      : "/gfx/hamburger-menu.png",
  },
};
</script>
```

and I get the error saying :

```
TypeError
Cannot read property 'white' of undefined
```

I have tried to validate the props and set it to not required like so:

```
  props: {
    white: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: false,
      default: false,
    },
  },
```

But it didn't help, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a `data` variable that depends of another variable, you must use a computed property.

You have to check about that on de official docs: [Computed Properties](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html)

And instead of hamburguerUrl on data, you put it on the computed propert

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "HamburgerMenu",
  props: ["white"],
  computed: {
    hamburgerUrl() {
      return this.white
        ? "/gfx/hamburger-white.png"
        : "/gfx/hamburger-menu.png";
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

And that's all.